# How to reduce computation time for nested loop when finding rows based on certain condition from dataset of more than 2M rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested-loops

I have a large dataset for 2M rows which columns as warehouse code, part code, transport mode, time_taken. there are 10 ways for shipping a product, I wanted to find the transport mode which took the least time for each product. There are 10 different warehouses and more than 2700 unique products. I wanted to find the least time taken for each product in the data set. I have written this function but  This code is taking more than 14Hr to execute can anyone share a better solution to this problem

```
def model_selection_df(df):
    value =pd.DataFrame()
    for WH in Whse:
        wh_df = df[df['WAREHOUSE_CODE']==WH]
        unique_SKU = wh_df['VEND_PART'].unique()
        for part in unique_SKU:
            df_1 = wh_df[wh_df['VEND_PART']==part]
           
            other_method = wh_df[(wh_df['VEND_PART']==part) & (wh_df['TIME_TAKEN']== df_1['TIME_TAKEN'].min() )]
                       
            value= value.append(other_method)
                        
    return value
```

Comment: you probably want to use groupby like this `df.groupby(['WAREHOUSE_CODE', 'VEND_PART'])['TIME_TAKEN'].min()` its not very clear what you want to achive

Comment: you can use GPU optimizations, if your loop is not dependant on the previous one

Comment: I wanted to restore all columns from dataframe, by doing groupby i will only be getting 3 columns WAREHOUSE_CODE, VENT_PART  and time_taken